# How to compare and update an Eloquent Collection based on another Collection in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, collections, eloquent, laravel-collection

I have a model in Laravel called `Player`. This player data is pulled from an external API. I am trying to update this external data on a scheduled basis from the external API. The external API data is the authoritative source on what should be in the `players` table.

What I currently have is two collections, one is the data from the database, the other is the external API data. I constructed new `Player` models in a collection based on the API data.

What I essentially have right now is this:

```
Collection $playersInDatabase; // Eloquent Collection of type Player
Collection $playersFromApi; // Collection of type Player
```

The `$playersFromApi` data is just the JSON API data converted into new Player models and added to the collection.

My problem is that I can't just wipe the whole `players` table as I am only modifying a subset of the table at a time. Is there an effective way to use Laravel to compare these two? I want to add any new Player models to the database that don't exist, update any existing Player model that has differing data, and then also delete any records that the API data no longer has but are still in the database (stale records).

The only way I can think of to do this involves iterating over the collections multiple times to accomplish what I want to do and I feel like there is an easier more elegant way to do this that better utilizing the framework.

For reference here is what the `players` table looks like. I am currently using seeder data:

[image: example table]

Comment: does the API return the whole players base?

Comment: @Musa No it does not. There are factions/clans in this. Via the API you can get the players of one "faction" at a time. I am only storing a 6-7 factions worth of players. Essentially what happens is that the players within a faction are changing all the time. So I want to periodically update my data of players in a faction. So it means sometimes a new player joins (create new Player), sometimes they leave (delete Player), and sometimes they will do something like change their name (update Player). I can use something like `diffAssoc` on the collection but it feels clunky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this. No comparisons necessary, just `updateOrCreate()` and delete any ids not updated for the corresponding faction in a single DB call.

```php
// the faction id you are querying from API
$faction_id = ...;

// for storing updated model ids
$updated_ids = [];

foreach ($playersFromApi as $playerFromApi) {

    // update record or create a new one
    $player = Player::updateOrCreate(
        [
            // conditions to meet
            '...' => $playerFromApi['...']
        ],
        [
            // data to update   
            '...' => $playerFromApi['...']
        ]

    );

    // store id of updated model
    $updated_ids[] = $player->id;
}


// delete models not updated
Player::where('faction_id',$faction_id)->whereNotIn('id',$updated_ids)->delete();
```

Comment: As the data from the API I already have passed to this as a new Player model when using `updateOrCreate` am I able to just pass the whole model or do I have to list out each field and value like you have shown in the example?

Comment: As you have not posted any code, I'm not sure I understand your question. It sounds like you're planning to run `updateOrCreate()` twice, which is not necessary. If you are already updating the DB in a prior step, you would just integrate this into your existing code at that point.  Also, the `updateOrCreate()` method accepts arrays, not models.  If all fields in the array correspond to fields in the DB, there is no harm in passing an entire array. If not, then you would need to list them individually.

Comment: Awesome, what I meant was that my data from the external API I already had put into a Player model so I was wondering if that could be passed instead but it looks like the answer is no. I did it the way you showed in your answer and it worked for me! This is much easier than the solution I was working on! Thanks

Comment: Related quick side question, I don't see it in the Eloquent ORM docs is there a way to determine if a record was created or updated via this command? I am thinking I am probably going to want to do something extra after this with any "new" players that were created.

Comment: There are several methods you could use. The most straightforward is simply `$player->wasRecentlyCreated` which will return a boolean value. However, depending on your use case, you may want to take a look at [Eloquent Events](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#events). They can be defined as a [Closure](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#events-using-closures) within a model, or as a separate [Observer](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#observers) class.

Comment: Great, thanks, that is super helpful! I think for now the straightforward way will work for me, but if I do anything more to it I may try and learn more about the other options you mentioned. Appreciate all the support! As a side note I don't even see `wasRecentlyCreated` in the Laravel documentation which is a bit annoying. Makes it hard to find useful stuff like this.